# Large variable memory problems

Tags: memory, asp-classic

I'm looping through a table in my MSSQL database, and building up a variable to hold some data. There's 3000+ rows in the table.

My problem is that the system loads forever when I call the function. If I disable the variable-buildup, the query executes in a few seconds.

Example:

```
Set rs = dbConn.Execute("Select x, y, z From MyTable")  
Do until rs.EOF  
strData = strData & rs("x") & ","  
strData = strData & rs("y") & ","  
strData = strData & rs("z") & vbCrlf  
rs.MoveNext  
Loop  
Set rs = Nothing
```

Finally I do:

```
Response.Clear
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=export.csv"
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.Write strData
Response.End
```

How can I do this instead?

Comment: Stream it? disable buffering, call AddHeader & ContentType, run the loop and Write then Flush every *n* iterations, empty the string then continue looping.

Comment: Of course! Works perfect. Thank you.